# Magento 2, One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: magento-2.1, indexing, mamp

I need assistance in this index error message that appears in admin area:

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.

I'm using MAMP on Mac.

Comment: You have to run indexing command from your server root path, php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup and run cron in the background.

On your Mac, open Terminal:

> `crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e`

then

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

More details: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

You set up cron for this error like @WaPoNe answered.

Or you go to in your Magento root directory.

`htdocs/magentdirectory/`

And open your terminal and execute below command.

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.